# Convert nested foreach-loops with 3 levels to recurrence with n levels

Tags: c#, recursion

I want to convert the following code to handle more than 3 foreach-levels.

```
internal static void CreateLevel(LevelObject levelObject)
{
   foreach(LevelObject l1 in levelObject.LevelObjects)
   {
      foreach(LevelObject l2 in l1.LevelObjects)
      {
         foreach(LevelObject l3 in l2.LevelObjects)
         {
            AddEntities(l3);
         }
         AddEntities(l2);
      }
      AddEntities(l1);
   }
}
```

Every LevelObject has a collection of child-level-objects, a collection of entities and a parent-level-object. 
I need this to convert an object-structure to a filter.
Anyone has an idea how to convert this?

Comment: Did you try a recursive algorithm?

Comment: Add a few nested `foreach`s :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is to recurse:

```
internal static void CreateLevel(LevelObject levelObject) {
    foreach (var l in levelObject.LevelObjects) {
        CreateLevel(l);
        AddEntities(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but with no bounding case, this might go wrong. Depends what data is thrown at it. Might be better to include a level so we can stop stop recursing at depth n

Comment: But he probably wants to change his code because he wants more than 3 levels.

Comment: Saw that and corrected to `n`, but without further thought of bounding-cases, this *could* stackoverflow. It **will** SO if the graph is cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code...

```
internal static void CreateLevel(LevelObject levelObject)
{
   foreach(LevelObject l1 in levelObject.LevelObjects)
   {
      CreateLevel(l1.LevelObjects);
      AddEntities(l1);
   }
}
```

Will accomplish the same goal